# Parse a variable that contains velocity formula

Tags: velocity

I have a problem. I need to parse a variable that contains velocity formula e.g.

```
set($test = $tests.get("test1"))
$test
```

while `$tests.get("test1")` returns a velocity formula and it doesn't work.

I tried to use `parse` but it's for files and I retrieve `$tests.get("test1")` it from db and I cant save it into files. I also tried to use `#evaluate` but it doesn't do anything.

This is my html:

```
// test now contains a velocity formula
#set($test = $sections.get("test"))  
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
#evaluate($test)
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show a formula example and how you were using `#evaluate`?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what #evaluate is for.  An alternative would be the RenderTool from Velocity tools.  You are probably using #evaluate incorrectly.